# hadoop hive data loading

Tags: json, hive

I have json data in the below format and I just need the "text" field to be inserted into a table in hive.

```
[
  {
    "fullname": "Jia Khan",   
    "id": "832576802904240129",
    "likes": "1",
    "replies": "0",
    "retweets": "0",
    "text": "This is gonna be an intense showdown only if the weather showed some mercy. @PeshawarZalmi #AbKhelJamayGa #PZvQG #HarDilZalmi #HBLPSL",
    "timestamp": "2017-02-17T13:05:52",
    "user": "iamJiaKhan"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First , you can create a temporary table for all the data field then you can create a final table by selecting only one required field from temporary table.